# calculating kurtosis array[Double] filed in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics

how to calculate the kurtosis of array field in spark

spark built-in function is failing array field.

`due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires double type, however, 'SERIES' is of array<double> type.;;`

Example in python

```
 from scipy.stats import kurtosis
 kurtosis([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
-1.3
```

i used spark built in function

```
df.withColumn("newcolumn",when(col("SERIES").isNotNull,kurtosis(columnName))
```

Comment: What code did you use to get the error message?

Comment: Please post the code and error

Comment: I added my code. @SarathChandraVema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Twitter Algebra  package i can get kurtosis value.

```
import com.twitter.algebird._
val y  = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
def getMoments(xs: List[Int]): Moments =
xs.foldLeft(MomentsGroup.zero) { (m, x) =>
  MomentsGroup.plus(m, Moments(x))
}

println(getMoments(y).kurtosis) // -1.3
```